# How I can make the two products free in magento?

Tags: magento, coupon

I have a category "Free Samples" and want the first 2 products in that category to be free and the rest to cost their original price.
So lets say the user adds these products to their cart:
sample1 - $8.00
sample2 - $8.00
sample3 - $8.00

sample1 and sample2 should be free and sample3 should $8.00 with the cart total being $8. How can I do this using the Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this document to make rule in Magento

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a coupon, caled Price rule in Magento and use the following conditions.

E.x. 
If **ALL** of these conditions are **TRUE**:

sample1 *sku* **is** x

sample2 *sku* **is** x